# Errors after proguarding android project gson

Tags: android, gson, proguard

After running proguard on my project everything is well but i got a problem with that. I use specification for gson in rules but i still got this kind of error. Normally this code works well. Hmm do any1 have any ideas?

```
com.google.gson.p: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "1271.jpg"
            at com.google.gson.b.a.q$29.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.gson.b.a.q$29.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.gson.b.a.k$1.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.gson.b.a.l.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.gson.d.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.gson.d.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.gson.d.a(Unknown Source)
            at pl.app.model.f.a(Unknown Source)
            at pl.app.fragment.g.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.i(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.m.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.m.b(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.f(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.o.b(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.c(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17479)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17479)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17479)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17479)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17479)
            at net.simonvt.menudrawer.OverlayDrawer.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17479)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17479)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:412)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17479)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2532)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17479)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2262)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1391)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1590)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6585)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "1271.jpg"
            at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
            at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:
```

My proguard file:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keepattributes Signature,RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,AnnotationDefault,*Annotation*
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgent
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
-dontwarn com.commonsware.cwac.merge.**

-keep class org.xmlpull.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**


## Gson
-keepattributes Signature
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

## Joda time
-dontwarn org.joda.convert.**

## Guava
-keep,allowoptimization class com.google.inject.** { *; }
-keep,allowoptimization class javax.inject.** { *; }
-keep,allowoptimization class javax.annotation.** { *; }
-keep,allowoptimization class com.google.inject.Binder

## CouchBase-Lite
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
-keep public enum * { public static **[] values(); public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String); }
-keepnames class com.codehaus.jackson.** { *; }
-keep class org.ektorp.** { *; }
-keep class com.couchbase.cblite.router.CBLRouter { *; }
-keep class com.couchbase.touchdb.TDCollateJSON { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * { native <methods>; }

## Picasso
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

## Zxing
-keep class com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.open.**
-keep class com.google.zxing.client.android.common.executor.**

-keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

-keepclassmembers,allowoptimization class com.google.common.* {
    void finalizeReferent();
    void startFinalizer(java.lang.Class,java.lang.Object);
}

#eventbus
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    public void onEvent*(**);
}


-dontnote android.**
-dontnote java.**
-dontnote javax.**
-dontnote junit.**
-dontnote org.**
-dontnote dalvik.**
-dontnote com.android.internal.**

# Stop warnings about missing unused classes
-dontwarn com.google.common.**
-dontnote com.google.common.**
```

Comment: Did you obfuscate the classes you're trying to (de-)serialize? This may cause the mapping between Java and JSON fields to break.

Comment: I obfuscate models . But i use models in every module in my app. And only in 1 it doesnt not work.

Comment: Btw you was right. This model has unique field that wasnt working.

Answer (score 0):

I use this config for my GSON proguarding,try it and let me know

```
## GSON 2.2.4 specific rules ##

# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keepattributes EnclosingMethod

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }
```